# Postfix server and Simplenews module interaction

Tags: 7, emails

I send newsletters from my Drupal-7 website to all its registered users, using Simplenews module. As this number grows, I want to be able to track the number of successful and unsuccessful sends.
In my site, there is a postfix server installed, whose logs may give me a hint on how many mails were not delivered.
Although, the log file is a chaotic file -300.000 rows or even more- and the mails might be about something else, like registration for example.
I want to be able to track better how many of the newsletters were successfully delivered, in integration with my postfix server.
Or if you can suggest a better way to achieve that.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a [Reply-To:] header to your mails. Maybe your postfix will send the non-delivery notifications to this address.